# Elm's Time is not Precise, is it?

Tags: time, floating-point, elm

I've been toying with `Effects.tick` and `Time` in one of my apps, and I can't seem to get my delays to be around the `Time.second` that it claims to be. It's nearly immediate. I understand that `type alias Time = Float`, and from my logs it seems that `second = 1000`, but this just burns so quickly, even with logging. Is there a clear explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Effects.tick` causes an action to be called nearly instantaneously, but the action that is being called gets passed a value of the current time of the tick. If you want to delay something by a second while using `Effects.tick`, you'll have to keep track of a starting point and compare it to the time of the current tick, and that's where you can add in `Time.second`.

Take this arbitrary example (you can paste it into http://elm-lang.org/try):

```elm
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import StartApp
import Effects exposing (Never)
import Task
import Signal
import Time exposing (..)

app =
  StartApp.start
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , inputs = [  ]
    }

main =
  app.html

type alias Model =
  { lastTick : Maybe Time
  , tickEverySecond : Maybe Time
  }

init =
  ({ lastTick = Nothing, tickEverySecond = Nothing }, Effects.tick MyTicker)

view address model =
  div [] 
    [ div [] [ text <| "Current tick: " ++ (toString model.lastTick) ]
    , div [] [ text <| "Updated every second: " ++ (toString model.tickEverySecond) ]
    ]

type Action
  = MyTicker Time

update action model =
  let
    everySecond = Maybe.withDefault 0 model.tickEverySecond
    getTickEverySecond time =
      if time > everySecond + Time.second then
        Just time
      else
        Just everySecond
  in
    case action of
      MyTicker time -> (
        { model | lastTick = Just time
        , tickEverySecond = getTickEverySecond time
        }, Effects.tick MyTicker)

port tasks : Signal (Task.Task Never ())
port tasks =
  app.tasks
```

Every `update` call requests a new tick, so it will just spin forever. The important part is that `tickEverySecond` is only updated if the last time it was updated is greater than one second ago.

You ask about the time precision. If you run that example, you'll notice that the increment every second is somewhat approximate; it will drift greater than a second. That isn't due to any kind of underlying imprecision. Remember that Elm's `Time` functionality is a thin veneer over Javascript's time and timer functionality. That drift is merely an artifact of all the tiny little delays caused by running code that responds to a timer signal.